# Finding $E(N_{2}\mid N_{1} + N_{3})$ where $N_{t}$ is a Poisson process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, poisson-process

$N_{t}$ is a Poisson process.

So: We can try to find it by definition:

$$
\phi (z) = E(N_{2}\mid N_{1} + N_{3} = z)
$$
And use total probability rule, but it'll just leave us with some series, which might diverge:

\begin{align}
\phi(z) &= \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}kP(N_{2}=k\mid N_{1}+N_{3} = z) 
\\&=  \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}\frac{P(N_{1}=j, N_{2} - N_{1} = k - j, N_{3} - N_{2} = z - k - j)}{P(N_{1}=j, N_{3}-N_{1} = z - 2j)} 
\\&= \cdots =\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} k\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}C_{z-2j}^{k-j}2^{2j - z}
\end{align}

And I was wondering if there was some easier way to compute this conditional expectation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the three increments
$$X = N_1, \qquad Y = N_2 - N_1, \qquad Z = N_3 - N_2 .$$
These are independent Poisson random variables each with parameter $\lambda$. Instead of conditioning on $N_1 + N_3$, suppose we condition on both $N_1$ and $N_3 - N_1$. This amounts to conditioning on both $X$ and on $Y+Z$:
$$ \begin{align*} E(N_2 | N_1, N_3-N_1) &= E(X+Y | X,Y+Z) \\ &= X + E(Y | X, Y+Z) \\ &= X + \frac 1 2 (Y+Z) . \end{align*}$$
The final line comes from the fact that if $U$ and $V$ are independent Poisson variables with paremeters $\lambda$ and $\mu$, respectively, then the distribution of $U$ conditional on $U+V$ is binomial with probability $\frac{\lambda}{\lambda + \mu}$ and with $U+V$ trials. See the second bullet point [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution#General) for this fact. This has now worked out very conveniently for us, because
$$ X + \frac 1 2 (Y+Z) = \frac 1 2 (N_1 + N_3) $$
so that, by repeated conditioning,
$$ \begin{align*} E(N_2 | N_1 + N_3) &= E\Big( E(N_2 | N_1, N_3-N_1) \, \Big| \, N_1 + N_3 \Big) \\ &= E \Big( \frac 1 2 (N_1 + N_3) \, \Big| \, N_1 + N_3 \Big) \\ &= \frac 1 2 (N_1 + N_3) . \end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks! I have a question though. Why is $$E(Y | X, Y+Z) = \frac 1 2 (Y+Z) $$If it is binomial distribution? Does the sum of two poisson processes also have binomial distribution?

Comment: $X$ is independent of both $Y$ and $Z$, so $E(Y | X, Y+Z) = E(Y|Y+Z)$. Now from the fact mentioned, because $Y$ and $Z$ are independent Poisson with parameter $\lambda$, the distribution of $Y$ conditional on $Y+Z$ is binomial with probability 1/2 and with $Y+Z$ trials. This is what gives a conditional expectation of $\frac 1 2 (Y+Z)$.

Comment: Hmm, alright. Another question. Why is $E(Y|X,Y+Z) = E(Y|Y+Z)$? Like, if X and Y are independent, doesn't it mean, that $E(Y|\sigma(X, Y+Z)) = E(Y) = $ const?

Comment: The idea here is that, when conditioning on both $X$ and $Y+Z$, $X$ does not tell us information about $Y$ because of independence, but $Y+Z$ could, since it involves $Y$. The equation can be checked using the definition of conditional expectation; integrate $E(Y | Y+Z)$ against against a random variable of the form $1_{\{X \in B_1\}} 1_{\{Y+Z \in B_2\}}$ for Borel sets $B_1, B_2$.